# Oracle estimate cardinality on partitioned table

Tags: oracle, optimization, partitioning

How does Oracle estimate cardinality on a partitioned table if the query gets the list of partitions from a subquery or a join?

For example, if I have a query like this

```
select * from partitioned_table 
   join list_of_partitions using (part_key)
```

Assume `list_of_partitions` is a small table (single row per partition key)

What estimate gets used for `partitioned_table`?

Since Oracle doesn't know exactly what partitions are accessed when the query is parsed, where would the estimate come from?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Everything depends on how the table is partitioned and whether the indexes are local are global.

Comment: Agreed with Phil - the optimizer has a lot of tricks to choose from for this, including magical bloom-filter based partition join filters... and a lot of stats to choose from too if you have partition-level and global stats for the table and indexes.